# fill in automatic way a form using php and ajax

Tags: php, mysql, json, ajax

I've a simple table on mysql like this

```
----------------
id | film | year
----------------
1  | xxxx | 2000
----------------
2  | yyyy | 2001
----------------
```

I'd like to create a form with 3 fields that when i put the number 1 in the field ID it gives to me automatically xxxx in the field "film" and "2000" in the field year.

I know how to do it with a php Post but i need it without button

Comment: yes...but i don't know how to do...could you post an example or a link where I can see a similar thing?

Answer (score 0):

all you need to do is have the onchange flag in the html elements and have that pass its data and what field it is to a javascript ajax handler that sends a post to a php script that hits the database with your query and returns the data to javascript which can then be used to populate the Fields.

Comment: i mean i could just write the whole thing for you but that's not really what this is for. and you wouldnt learn anything,  i mean i would recommend that you watch the newbostons ajax series as it is a good tutorial for what you are looking for https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tp3Gw-oWs2k&list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGDiJSXfsJTASx9eMq_HlenQ